# SSRS - remove last character in string if character is comma ','

Tags: reporting-services, sql-server-2014

In my SSRS report the query I'm using concats multiple strings based on value:

```
CONCAT(
    CASE WHEN tu.TU_Ht_NREZ = 1 THEN 'Nichtraumzimmer, ' ELSE '' END,
    CASE WHEN tuex.Doppelzimmer = 1 THEN 'Doppelzimmer, ' ELSE '' END,
    CASE WHEN tuex.AllergikerBettwaesche = 1 THEN 'Allergiker Bettwäsche, ' ELSE '' END,
    CASE WHEN tu.TU_Ht_VegEssen = 1 THEN 'Vegetarisch, ' ELSE '' END,
    CASE WHEN tu.TU_Ht_SchwbEZ = 1 THEN 'Schwerbehindert, ' ELSE '' END,
    CASE WHEN tuex.VeganesEssen = 1 THEN 'Veganes Essen, ' ELSE '' END,
    CASE WHEN tuex.GlutenfreiseKost = 1 THEN 'Glutenfreie Kost, ' ELSE '' END,
    CASE WHEN tuex.Rollstuhl= 1 THEN 'Rollstuhl' ELSE '' END
    ) AS TeilnehmerBemerkung
```

However, if the 'Rollstuhl' is not added to the string, then the whole string has comma ',' at the end.

How could I check if last character is ',' and replace it with '' ? I can't use STRING_AGG is not available in SQL Server 2014.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the `CASE` is done, you could check the string if the last character is a comma and do some `CASE`-ing to replace it.

```
DECLARE @s NVARCHAR(100)= 'a,b,c,';
SET @s = CASE WHEN RIGHT(@s, 1) = ',' THEN SUBSTRING(@s,1,LEN(@s)-1) ELSE @s
         END;

SELECT  @s;
```

`@s` is your string with all the concatenation work.